# Decode GPS hex data from Zenec trk files

Tags: c#, gps, hex

I am trying to write a program in C# to convert the following raw data in the trk files downloaded from my Zenec GPS unit into a more readable format

```
4A23EA5899007C06E33E451CFC0300009C190000
```

The data shown on my Zenec for the abowe line that I'm aiming for:

```
Time: 2017-04-09 12:04:26
Latitude: 56.540981650
Longitude: 12.968768239
Altitude: 20.0
Speed(km/h): 6.6
```

I have managed to decode the first 4 bytes `4A23EA58` into the date and time `"2017-04-09 12:04:26"` but I don't seem to be able to decode the rest. I have been in contact with the supplier of the unit but they was not able to help.

Grateful for any help 
//Stig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out for the time & date, these are 32-bit little endian numbers.

> 0x58EA234A = decimal 1491739466

Using that as the number of seconds since 1-1-1970 yields the desired date. 
 Trying the same approach for the next 4 bytes gives the following:

> 0x067C0099 = decimal 108789913

But that doesn't look like a floating-point degrees.  Perhaps it's scaled?

> 108789913 / 2^23 = **12.968768**

...the desired longitude.  Next:

> 0x1C343EE3 = decimal 473186019
>   
>   473186019 / 2^23 = **56.408169**

...the desired latitude.  Next

> 0x000003FC = decimal 1020
>   0x0000199C = decimal 6556

6556 could be the speed:

> 6556 / 10^3 = **6.556**, which rounds to **6.6**

Unfortunately, I can find no nice scaling to get 20m from 1020, even if I try other altitude units:

> 20.0m = 65.6168ft = 787.402in = 21.8723yds

None of those values scale by a nice factor to 1020.  A scaling factor of 51 is not nice, but maybe that's what they did:

> 1020 / 51 = **20.0**

#### Update

It occurred to me that the altitude could have an offset of +1000.  There are negative elevations on Earth, so to avoid requiring a *signed* number, they may have added 1000 to all altitudes to guarantee a positive number.  That can be stored in an *unsigned* number.  **You really need some more data points.**

On one hand, I'd be surprised if they are only reporting integer (whole) meters, since the GPS device reports with 1 or 2 digits after the decimal point.

OTOH, GPS altitude isn't that accurate, and most hikers don't need to know the elevation down to the cm.

Comment: Thanks, that was the most perfect answer I could ever had hope for.